Swift decoding JSON object with multiple objects in it
I got a little lost while trying to decode a JSON object with multiple objects within it in from an API call. Hopefully I can get some guidance/examples of how to solve it.
This is the JSON object:
{
  "item_info": {
    "name": "Example Name",
    "movie_image": "https://google.com",
    "youtube_trailer": "123",
    "description": "lorem ispum",
    "backdrop_path": [
      "https://google.com"
    ],
    "video": {
      "index": 0,
      "codec_name": "h264",
      "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
      "profile": "High",
    },
    "audio": {
      "index": 1,
      "codec_name": "aac",
      "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
      "profile": "LC",
    }
  },
  "movie_data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Example Name",
    "added": "1663373489",
    "secondary_id": "298",
  }
}


The added parameter looks like it might be a Unix epoch date value, i.e., a timeIntervalSince1970 date. But this is typically a numeric value, not a string. We can write a custom decoder for that, but it would be better to fix the source, if you can.

The QuickType.io site, as suggested by Bhagwan Ranpura (+1), can jumpstart this for you. Once you clean up the code a bit, you might end up with something like:
struct Item: Codable {
    let itemInfo: ItemInfo
    let movieData: MovieData
}

// MARK: - ItemInfo
struct ItemInfo: Codable {
    let name: String
    let movieImage: String                    // possibly `URL` would be more appropriate
    let youtubeTrailer, description: String
    let backdropPath: [String]                // possibly `[URL]` would be more appropriate
    let video, audio: Media
}

// MARK: - Media
struct Media: Codable {
    let index: Int
    let codecName, codecLongName, profile: String
}

// MARK: - MovieData
struct MovieData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name, added, secondaryId: String
}

and then you can decode it:
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let object = try decoder.decode(Item.self, from: data)
    print(object)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

Note, the Quicktype.io site will suggest explicit CodingKeys to map between the snakecase keys in the JSON and the swifty camelcase naming convention, but this can be achieved more economically by specifying a keyDecodingStrategy for your JSONDecoder of convertFromSnakeCase, reducing the amount of noise in the code.

As an aside, looking at the JSON, it looks like movie_image and backdrop_path might be URL and [URL] types, respectively, but you would want to look at the documentation for the source of this JSON to confirm whether they will always be URLs or not. Likewise, when looking at a short JSON, we cannot be sure whether some of these properties should be optional, so again, you would want to refer to the documentation.
But hopefully this gets you started.
